# How to connect the phone to the computer

Tags: flutter, android-emulator, adb

I connected my laptop and mobile phone to a Wi-Fi and connected the phone to the laptop with a USB cable and enabled USB debugging on the mobile phone and entered the commands adb tcpip 5555 and adb connect 192.168.1.51:5555 in the cmd of the laptop respectively.  And the mobile was successfully connected to the laptop, but when I disconnect the USB cable, the connection is disconnected, and without connecting the cable, the command adb connect... does not work, my Android mobile is 10 and it does not have wireless debugging, I tried using wifi direct as well.  Connect, which recognized the laptop but did not connect

Please guide me how to connect my mobile, I want to use for flutter in vscode

adb connect and wifi direct

Comment: "and without connecting the cable, the command adb connect... does not work" what exact error do you see?

Comment: What is wrong with the adb connection over USB? Note that the adb connection over TCP has to be res-established using USB every time you reboot the phone.

Comment: Cannot connect to 192.168.1.51:5555: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. (10061)

Comment: ask google for: `adb error 10061` - it returns a lot of useful links

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.